# Branch specific includes for gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci

Situation: We have a large project, where the developer should be able to skip some test on his branch for focussing on the specific changes he made. We don't want that everyone changes the .gitlab-ci.yaml, because this could end in a lot of merge conflicts.

The idea was to make branch-specific includes like

```
include:
  - local: branch/${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-config.yaml
```

In the include there should be some Variables defined, which then influence the jobs, which must be run.

Unfortunately this is not directly supported by [gitlab-ci](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/24811).

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved it with the following work-around.
We parse the commit-message to decide which job must run, this can be easily done with rules.

```
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME || $JOBNAME'
      when: never
    - if: '$CONFIG_CI =~ /.*customer.*IPONA.*/i'
    - if: '$CONFIG_CI'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /CC:.*@customer@.*-IPONA-.*/i'
```

Further more we have an directory branch/config which contains a file with configuration-option.
With the following hook-skript we ensure that the data from config-file must not be added every commit.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Use in prepare-commit-msg-hook
# add a CC to the Commit-message to configure CI.

BRANCH_NAME=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
grep "CC:" $1

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo >> $1
  branch_config=gitlab-ci/config/branch/$BRANCH_NAME
  if [[ -f ${branch_config} ]]; then
    . ${branch_config}
    echo "CC: ${CONFIG_CI}" >> $1
  else
    echo "CC: @customer@-IPOFA-IPONA-HOLIA-INSCA-OUTCA-INTT-QAT-" >> $1
  fi
fi
```

Don't use this hack if [gitlab-ci issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/24811) is really solved.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should look at `only/except` of GitLab:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic

With this, it is possible to decide which jobs are run depending on many different things. If you use merge requests, it is possible to only run jobs when files in certain files have changed. Something like:

```
my_job:
  script:
    - build things
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
    changes:
      - path/to/somewhere/**/*
      - other/path/**/*
```

This is quite easy to set up and to understand.

If you really need developers to be able to manually choose which jobs to run, it should be possible. It might get a bit hacky though. If you have a branch name like `fix-bug-xyz_myvar-eq-42`, and then have jobs like:

```
job:
  script:
    - build things
  only:
    - /.*myvar-eq-.*/
```

They should only be run for branches that has the matching pattern inside of them. You could then use the variable `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` and split it to find the value of the variables set. I haven't tested this myself, but something like that should work.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately I knew them. This is a solution for small projects. On large projects the branch name becomes unreadable. Furthermore the idea is that you start hacking running a small testset, perhaps create a MR to get feedback. At the end of the process a greater testset should be run. If you change the branch-name you must create a new MR.
The idea with changes doesn't work because at a new branch all files are changed.

Comment: Only changes work fine, as long as you also use the `refs: merge_requests`. If all your jobs use this, no jobs are started when you push a new branch. Then when you create a merge request, GitLab will check  the diff between the source branch and target branch of your merge requests, and `only: changes` will make it so that only the jobs for the changed files are run.